# Как дебажить php проект?

Tags: php, html

Вопрос следующий - есть проект на PHP, стоит xdebug, есть форма

```
<form method="post" action="logon.php" class="login">
        <p>
            <label for="login">Логин:</label>
            <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="name@example.com">
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="password">Пароль:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </p>

        <p class="login-submit">
            <button type="submit" class="login-button">Войти</button>
        </p>

        <p class="forgot-password"><a href="index.html">Забыл пароль?</a></p>
        <p><a href="register.html">Регистрация</p>
    </form>
```

при включении дебага, глобальный масив $_POST пуст(и это понятно), как во время дебага передать данные с формы???

Comment: `глобальный масив $_POST пуст(и это понятно)` - Вообще не понятно! Вы не `logon.php` чтоли дебажите? "Как передать данные с формы?" - отправить форму.

Comment: я дебажу logon.php, но массив $_POST пуст, у меня идет проверка if (isset($_POST['submit'])) - если да, то выполняется код, но еще раз повторюсь $_POST пуст

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump ($_POST);
```

Всегда открывает много нового, неожиданного :)

Comment: Я видимо Ванга?

Comment: мне не нужно выводить этот массив или просматривать его, мне нужно во время дебага, чтобы он был с информацией с формы

Answer (score 0):

для передачи посредством post нужно использовать не `<button></button>`, а `<input type="submit" name="logon" value="Войти" class="login-button"/>`

Comment: У вас `IE<=6` ?

Comment: @vp_arth у автора нет имени кнопки просто